# What does this line of code do in bipartite graph algorithm through bfs?

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search, bipartite

I have been reading bipartite algorithm from https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bipartite-check.html and I encounter a line:

```
side[u] = side[v] ^ 1
```

What does this line of code do? What does ***^1*** means?

Tried googling it but didn't come up with any result.

Comment: ^ is the bitwise operatro for a XOR. So your code does an XOR operation on side[v] and 1 and save the result in side[u]

Comment: But why it needs to do XOR with 1??How does it help??

Comment: I don't know what this algorithm does, and too lazy right now to read, but `^ 1` expression change "oddness" of number, i.e. if number was odd it will be even, if it was even it will be odd. You can think of it like this: if number is even, then add 1, else substract 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` is a [bitwise xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operator in C++ (also in C, Java etc).

Bitwise xor of a bit(0/1) with 1 flips that bit, i.e.

```
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

As given on wikipedia

> The bitwise XOR may be used to invert selected bits in a register (also called toggle or flip). Any bit may be toggled by XORing it with 1.

In this algorithm, it is being used to decide the set in which node `u` should belong.
As `u` and `v` are connected (because `u` is in the adjacency list of `v`), so `u` should belong to the different set as `v` (property of bipartite graph).
The sets are being recorded in the `side[]` array which stores 0 or 1 for the two disjoint set of vertices, and `-1` as uninitialized value.